# Add a property on sonarqube using PropertyDefinition

Tags: plugins, properties, sonarqube

I have a plugin with some properties defined with Property class but I want to reorder them so I used PropertyDefinition class. The problem is that in the Property class there is a "project" field but not in PropertyDefinition. And when I run it with PropertyDefinition, there are 0 settings.
Here is the previous code:

```
@Properties({
    @Property(key = TestLinkPlugin.AAA, defaultValue = "false", name = "aa", description = "aa", project = true, type = PropertyType.BOOLEAN),...})
 @Override
public void define(Context context) {
    context.addExtensions(getExtensions());
}
```

And the new code:

```
@Override
public void define(Context context) {
    context.addExtension(
            PropertyDefinition.builder(TestLinkPlugin.AAA)
                    .name("aa")
                    .description("aa")
                    .defaultValue("false")
                    .type(PropertyType.BOOLEAN)
                    .index(0)
                    .build()
    );
   ...
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I have found the soltuion, add this :

```
.onQualifiers(Qualifiers.PROJECT)
```